# $_Session['registrationError'] is NOT setting errors for Registration form

Tags: php, forms, session, registration, user-registration

I am trying to create a `registration.php` form.

- The registration page checks for 'registrationError' and prints it, else it prints the registration form.
- The registration form accepts `first name` and `last name` fields.
- If the submit button is clicked it calls:
  `onClick="registrationValidator();"`

Here is the form in the *registration.php* page

```
  <?php  session_start(); require_once 'inc/functions.php';

if(sessionCheck('registrationError')) { //If session variable is set and not null

  foreach ($_Session['registrationError'] as $assoc) {
    echo $assoc;
  }
} else {  ?>

<form class="registrationBox" method="post">
    <div id="profileInfo">
      <label class="label">First Name </label><br />
        <input type="text" name="memberFirstName"><br />
      <label class="label">Last Name </label><br />
        <input type="text" name="memberLastName"><br />
      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" onClick="registrationValidator();">
     </div>
</form>
<?php } ?>
```

- Next, the `registrationValidator()` which is in `functions.php`checks if the `submit` button is set, if no, it sets `$_Session['registrationError']`, but if submit is set, it checks if the `first name` and `last name` are set, if there also set it does "some" query, ELSE `$_Session['registrationError']` is set.

Here is the function `registrationValidator()` in functions.php page.

```
/********** Registration Validator **********/

function registrationValidator() {

// Escape form fields from SLQ injections.
$mFirstName = escape($_POST['memberFirstName']);
$mLastName = escape($_POST['memberLastName']);
$submit = escape($_POST['submit']);

if(isset($submit)) {
        if(isset($mFirstName)) {
            doSLQ();

        } else {
            $_Session['registrationError'] = 'Name field not set';
        } if(isset($password)) {
                doSLQ();
        } else {
            $_Session['registrationError'] = 'Password field is not set';
        }

    } else {
        $_Session['registrationError'] = 'Did not submit';
    }

}
```

Additional, here is the `sessionCheck()` function that checks if a Session if set.

```
/********** Perform Session Check **********/
// takes a string as an argument and checks id a session variable with that string as its name has a value assigned to it
function sessionCheck($sessionVariable) {
    // checks if there is a session variable with the same name as the argument string
        if(isset($_SESSION[$sessionVariable])) {
      // if there is a session variable with the same name as the argument string, return true as the output of this function
            return true;
        }   else {
      // if there is not a session variable with the same name as the argument string, return false as the output of this function
            return false;
        }
}
```

I know that the `$_Session['registrationError']` is not being set for some reason because when I DON'T enter a first name and/or last name it does not print the error on top of `registration.php` page. I don't understand why? Any ideas?

Comment: use `$_SESSION` not `$_Session`.

Answer (score 0):

I guess your bit confused, when user clicked on submit button then onclick event event will fire and it will try to call JavaScript **registrationValidator()**, that method not seems to be there in JavaScript.

When user clicked the submit button, then it will search for the JavaScript registrationValidator(), and it will not invoke the server(PHP) registrationValidator() method.

registrationValidator() method will never invoked so thats why session is empty it not setting any time.

Comment: Then is there a way to invoke a PHP function on an HTML form?

Comment: You can't invoke php function from JavaScript, But you achieve this functionality in different way is create one one PHP file call 'validator.php' inside call include("functions.php');registrationValidator();. But this will solve your problem,

Comment: Okay, create a file for registrationValidator.php and include functions.php inside it. But how do I include registrationValidator.php  inside my form so when a user clicks it is called?

Comment: Send ajax post request